# How to not do anything on the "rest case" when matching a string?

Tags: rust

I have a string where I want to check if it's a semicolon, comma or colon. If it's not any of those, I don't want to do anything:

```
match token.as_ref() {
    ";" => semicolons += 1,
    "," => commas += 1,
    ":" => colons += 1,
     _ => println!(""),
}
```

This works, but I don't really want to print a bunch of empty lines (cause a lot of the tokens don't match these criteria).

What would be the most correct way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "most correct"?

Comment: I'm not very good at Rust, but consider [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfa8afad72872d91daa97af65bb6a58e&version=stable), which is much more functional.

Comment: To me that's much less readable than the accepted answer

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-02-match.html#the-_-placeholder) (2nd edition) states:

> ```rust
> let some_u8_value = 0u8;
> match some_u8_value {
>     1 => println!("one"),
>     3 => println!("three"),
>     5 => println!("five"),
>     7 => println!("seven"),
>     _ => (),
> }
> ```
>
> **The () is just the unit value, so nothing will happen in the `_` case.** As a result, we can say that we want to do nothing for all the possible values that we don’t list before the `_` placeholder.

You can also [use an empty block expression `{}`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html)

Comment: The better answer is _don't introduce side effects when pattern matching_.

Comment: Is there something special about pattern matching in Rust which makes side effects there less desirable than in any other place?

Comment: Good point. I'll amend my statement to be _don't introduce side effects_ (if it can be helped). It's particularly glaring here for some reason... maybe because pattern matching is the building block of FP.

Comment: @erip Generally, yes, but there are times when e.g. you want to return early for one of the arms but do nothing otherwise.  I just ran into such a case, which drew me here.

Comment: @SilasBarta That doesn't sound right. Sounds like you could map to an `Option`

Comment: @erip No, I meant "do nothing on that loop iteration".  For the case I'm considering, the return value will always be an integer, it's just that sometimes the loop needs to keep going, and sometimes it knows enough to exit and return there.

Comment: @SilasBarta I do not understand the use case well enough, but it still seems like other constructs could be more useful without sacrificing abstractions. Not sure what they are in Rust, but dropWhile and takeWhile come to mind.

Comment: @erip Rust has FP features but is not an FP language; side effects are common. And match is not "the building block of FP", it's just one of several tools to do the complex transformations of data that are at the heart of FP. Other, non-FP languages have adopted it because of its general usefulness. "don't introduce side effects" is not "the better answer"; in fact it's off topic. People ask questions on SO because they have specific problems they're trying to solve, and it's really not appropriate to tell them to change their paradigm in this context.

Comment: @JimBalter There is no feature checklist which forces a boundary into whether a language is FP or not... but I'd say immutability-by-default and support for lambdas is a pretty good start... And match being a partial function falls squarely onto the shoulders of both of those. WRT to telling someone to change the paradigm? Changing the solution to use a `fold` is minor. Since you're reviving this, you've clearly found a reason to believe your comment is relevant... I just haven't found it.

Comment: My comment is obviously relevant, and nothing in the above refutes any of it. My comment stands and I won't engage further.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov What is the difference between using `()` and `{}`? I've seen code that uses both in the same `match`. For example: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/9a5b4850f8691505ed7135033c1c7976a2e890b0/alacritty/src/event.rs#L1282-L1285

Comment: @sam If you look at blame, this `{}` used to be `()` as well https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/commit/66d742d0596203af7ca0e5db47c5b5bc1cc18d91, I don't know why they changed it but there should be no difference.